# Adding Library to CMake on CLI

Tags: opencv, build, cmake, archlinux

I'm trying to build OpenCV with CUDA support using Arch Linux's AUR. In their [build configuration](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=opencv-git) some options are passed to CMake, I have modified those to add [CUDA features](https://gist.github.com/ad01e73f1071f6f765096afc4a69557d). Upon attempting compilation I get the following error:

```
[ 10%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_reg
In file included from /home/meurer/Downloads/opencv-git/src/modules/cudacodec/opencv_cudacodec_pch_dephelp.cxx:1:0:
/home/meurer/Downloads/opencv-git/src/opencv/modules/cudacodec/src/precomp.hpp:59:14: fatal error: dynlink_nvcuvid.h: No such file or directory
     #include <dynlink_nvcuvid.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [modules/cudacodec/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudacodec_pch_dephelp.dir/build.make:63: modules/cudacodec/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudacodec_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_cudacodec_pch_dephelp.cxx.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:6834: modules/cudacodec/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudacodec_pch_dephelp.dir/all] Error 2
```

I searched my filesystem and found the rogue header file in `/usr/include/nvidia-sdk/dynlink_nvcuvid.h`. Due to how AUR works, I believe I can only configure CMake via command line options (See links [1](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=opencv-git), [2](https://gist.github.com/ad01e73f1071f6f765096afc4a69557d) under `_cmakeopts=`...).

What argument can I pass to CMake to make it search for the appropriate libraries under the aforementioned directory, as well as the ones it already uses?

Comment: (1) You can always clone opencv source code, run cmake-gui or ccmake or run cmake and then search CMakeCache.txt for exact variable names. (2) You could check [opencv/cmake/FindCUDA.cmake](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/cmake/FindCUDA.cmake#L257) (3) If you don't use nvcuvid, it would be simpler to just not enable it. (4) Ideally, you should make your package to depend on [nvidia-sdk](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/nvidia-sdk/)